# Applying MozTransform (via JS) in non mozilla browsers

Tags: javascript, css, vendor-prefix

**Background info**

I'm developing a visual form designer in which people with no coding experience can drag around form fields to create forms and print them or save as a HTML document.

I introduced a way to draw straight lines that can also be slanted at any angle. I accomplished this by using a normal div with no height and using only the bottom border. And when I apply `CSS rotate transform` to the div, it can be angled at any degree.

**Problem**

In the designer, when the user changes the angle(slope) of the line, I apply the styles via Javascript. Something like this:

```
lineWrapper.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
lineWrapper.style.MozTransform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
```

When the user wants to save the form as HTML, I get the outerHTML and return it to the user. Here, if I'm using Chrome, the `MozTransform` property is not there in the generated HTML and if I'm in Firefox the `webkitTransform` is not there.

**Approaches I tried**

I tried to solve this in many ways:

- Instead of setting it via `style` property, I tried setting it via `style.cssText` property. It didn't work.
- I can take the `outerHTML` of the div during HTML generation and insert the properties, but it's a very messy thing to do.
- I can compromise by giving CSS classes for commonly used angles (0, 45, 90, 135, 180 etc), but I don't want to give up here too quickly.

So, I'm asking you guys - Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Shesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont set the style with '.style' instead use 'setattribute'. It should add both in both browsers. Also this will allow you to apply the style with one command.

```
 lineWrapper.setattribute("style", "-webkit-transform : rotate(" + angle + "deg); -moz-transform : rotate(" + angle + "deg)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a light weight jQuery plugin for rotation: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ .It's really easy to use, and you can return the current angel of any html element just by using: `.getRotateAngle()`

Documentation: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Documentation